# Passing Token from iphone / ios to a website

Tags: iphone, authentication, web, identity

I want to create and pass a authentication / identity token on iphone/ios and send that token to a website. The website can take this token and use this token to authenticate a user/login.
I dont know how to do this on ios, I was hoping anyone can help me on this. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

My approach in the past has been to use the [ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to send a request to your server with the login details.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768893/asihttprequest-https-with-ssl) addresses various security concerns with ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it. Like using core ios libraries.

Comment: Yes, you can make requests using Apple's built in libraries (I think `NSURLRequest` is the one you want, though I'm not certain), but using ASIHTTPRequest saves you a lot of work, especially with asynchronous requests.