# Secure SSL ASIHTTP request from iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, security, http

Using ASIHTTP on the iPhone I am making HTTP requests for things such as sign up and login. They often look something like this:

`http://xxxxx.com/signup.php?username=fakeusername&password=fakepassword`

From this I usually receive a `json` response which I then parse.

I would like to soon submit my app to the App Store and need to make this secure. From what I understand this involves encryption and SSL certificates.

I have never done anything like this before and was hoping to get pointed in the right direction. Example code, tutorials, advice, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use  this link it has explained things in details

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert

Comment: The accepted answer uses NSURLConnection. There is also a mention about ASIHTTP, but I could use a bit more information as I have very little understanding of what this topic is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got a few questions here:

To do ssl with ASIHTTPRequest, you just need to pass a https url instead of a http one.

you don't need an real SSL certificate, you can disable validation using: [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];

Yes, you're limited by what certificate signing authorities are supported by the iphone. So long as you stick to the big names it shouldn't really be an issue. (And as per 2. you can use a self signed certificate anyway.)

It seems CCATS not necessary anymore, you need an ERN instead - the process has changed, as of Summer 2010! See http://tigelane.blogspot.com/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html

for more details go through this
[ASIHTTPRequest: https with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768893/asihttprequest-https-with-ssl)

Comment: so is there no security at all with this approach?