# iPhone AppStore encryption export for openssl usage - How?

Tags: iphone, encryption, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using SSL in an iPhone App - Export Compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance)

I am in Germany, and I am using OpenSSL for encryption on my iPhone App.

How is the best way to get the app in the app store? Should I get a TSU-Notification, SNAP-R, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this question:

[Using SSL in an iPhone App - Export Compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance)

JosephH's answer to that question is probably quite relevant: it appears that these days Apple is accepting ERNs and you don't need CCATS. (However, Apple's current [iTunes connect document](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) still references the need for CCATS.)

This question is also related:

[Does my application "contain encryption"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to start by reading the Bureau of Industry and Security web site at http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption and then call the help desk at 202-482-0707 if you have questions about your specific application.

TSU only applies if your app is "publicly available" and the fact that you're using OpenSSL does not mean your app is authorized for export as well.