# Adding encryption to an iPhone app, how does it affect approval?

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store, appstore-approval

I am If I add encryption to an iPhone app (basically to encrypt a username/password when sending to the server), I will need to answer "Yes" to the question in iTunes connect of if I have added encryption to the app. I know that there are many laws about exporting encryption software outside of the US, which is why Apple makes us answer this question. How does adding encryption to an iPhone app affect approval times, in your experience, and are there any reasons why adding encryption to an app would make Apple reject it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [the app store approval process is off topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: You set "encryption" to "yes" only if your app implements a new type of encryption (or includes an ecryption library).  If you are using the iOS encryption libraries, then the answer is "no".

Answer (score 2):

There are several of those encryption questions and if it is for storing passwords, then you probably are OK (although I don't remember exactly). 
If you encrypt any kind of network traffic, however (even if it is just getting a page via HTTPS), then you'll need to register your app with the US government (if you are in the US). While you are obtaining that registration, Apple may let you sell your app in the US-only store.

Check this out:

[Using SSL in an iPhone App - Export Compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance)