# UICKeyChainStore for iOS keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

I'm really new wit iOS keychain and stumbled upon this framework called UICKeyChainStore [here](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore). I also saw a tutorial using the above mentioned framework on sharing your keychain across several apps [here](http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/).

In the framework site the developer mentions about saving to the keychain with this syntax:

```
[UICKeyChainStore setString:@"kishikawakatsumi" forKey:@"username" service:@"com.kishikawakatsumi"];

[UICKeyChainStore setString:@"password1234" forKey:@"password" service:@"com.kishikawakatsumi"];
```

Does that mean it stores the username and password separately? So how do i retrieve the username and password of the same person? I am clueless to GitHub environment. Tried looking for a forum on that particular framework in GitHub but couldn't find any. Hoping stackoverflow could shed some light on this matter...

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1):

After saving the values to the keychain, you should be able to retrieve them like this:

```
NSString *username = [UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@"username" service:@"com.kishikawakatsumi"];
NSString *password = [UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@"password" service:@"com.kishikawakatsumi"];
```

Comment: Can i do this when assigning to keychain: e.g.; `[UICKeyChainStore setString:@"password1234" forKey:@"michael" service:@"com.kishikawakatsumi"];`?
In that way i just need to call for key 'michael' for the password?

Comment: I haven't actually used UICKeyChainStore, but yeah, it looks like accessor methods for retrieving stored values are the various stringForKey: and dataForKey: methods.

Comment: Another thing... If i use KeyChain, does it mean i have to declare it as using cryptography during submission to iTunesconnect?

Comment: go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609259/adding-encryption-to-an-iphone-app-how-does-it-affect-approval OR this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance and this http://tigelane.blogspot.in/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html