# Encryption in an iPhone app; export compilance

Tags: iphone, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using SSL in an iPhone App - Export Compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance)

I am going to upload an iPhone app to the app store which uses REST webservice. I am using ASIHTTPRequest for making connection to the server and get datas. The following are the things to note

1. URL starts with "https"
2. `[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO]` (When set to yes, I am only getting SSL error messages.)

Should I say my app supports encryption while submitting to the app store?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from the description whether you are setting up an SSL tunnel successfully or just transferring a certificate for site authentication.

In either case, you should probably call the Department of Commerce / Bureau of Industry and Security help desk at 202-482-0707 and get some guidance about what, if any, export restrictions would apply.

There is also a web site at http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption

Answer (score -1):

You only need to explicitly say your app *"supports encryption"* is your app uses some other form of encryption that what Apple provides in public API:s.

Using `NSURLRequest` with a https address is a public API, and no extra work needed on your part.

If you compile and bundle OpenSSL into your app yourself… well that is a completely different story and you are into allot of extra work.

Comment: You can find the actual (burdensome, unreasonable, ineffective and confusing) regulations on the Bureaucratic Industry Suppression (BIS) website: bis.doc.gov/encryption/question4.htm