# GameCenter and security

Tags: ios, security, game-center

How can I make sure the data that people send to GameCenter (like score, and peer data exchange) is not tampered with? That is, the network data comes from securely stored data  (e.g. using [SQLCiphier](http://zetetic.net/software/sqlcipher)), and is not modified midway? Is this impossible without a custom server side implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invaiarbly you will encounter a [CWE-602: Client-Side Enforcement of Server-Side Security](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/602.html) violation.  So the answer is **no**,  you can't stop this.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a checksum in but that can obviously be defeated if the hacker figures it out. You could encrypt the data using a private key, but then you have to go through CCATS to get your app accepted.

Other than that you are pretty much stuck without using a server side validation.

Comment: It's my understanding that if you use Apple libraries to do encryption, you don't need to have special approval.

Comment: Keychain only, if you use LibCrypto you have to get certified. Looks like it got changed recently(ish). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance

Comment: There seems to be some confusion on this. I've read you have to get certified for LibCrypto, but according to this you do not. http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html