# Diffie-Hellman implementation for iOS?

Tags: ios, diffie-hellman

This is my first question here as before I found all workarounds from another questions.

The question is very short: Does anyone know if there is any Diffie-Hellman implementation for iOS? I mean...the idea is to share between 2 devices (one is iOS and the other a java web service) a secret key, and I think the best idea should be that method.

If not, can anyone suggest me another option?

I'm not an advanced developer, that's why i'm trying to check for a framework for this.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: In case you are not aware, there are restrictions on using encryption that will affect your app's approval when you submit to the App Store. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance

Answer (score 4):

Apple has an implementation of Diffie-Hellman in iOS as part of [Secure Transport](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/SecureNetworkCommunicationAPIs/SecureNetworkCommunicationAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172-CH13-CHDHDIBB). Here is the [Secure Transport Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000155)

I'm posting this answer on a very old question because it's still relevant and other questions might link to this one. Improving this question's completeness may help answer newer questions.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google gives;

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/dh-objc.asp

You should *really* look into just using SSL though instead of inventing your own security protocol.

Comment: yeah I forgot to mention I found that chilkat implementation. Problem is that it appears almost in every google result and its not free.

Comment: Free was not a requirement in the question :) Still, inventing your own security protocol when SSL is available sounds dodgy. Is there any special requirement that excludes SSL?

Comment: not at all, I'm just a newby in security development. I read that with SSL i'm enable to make a secure connection (which I think ASIHTTPRequest would be giving you this quiet easy) but it doesnt provide me a method to encrypt something and decrypt it from the other side right?

Comment: Communicating over a properly set up SSL connection encrypts everything, both server-to-client and client-to-server communication without you needing to do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can include openssl as a static library in your app project and use its [Diffie-Hellman](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/dh.html) functions. As Joachim rightly says though, if you're communicating to a web service the easiest and best approach is to use SSL.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Diffie-Hellman implementation for iOS in github.
You can use it.
https://github.com/benjholla/Diffie-Hellman-iOS
Also you can use openssl with ios. Considering openssl is a proven library, it is better to use openssl for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

There is a Diffie-Hellman implementation for iOS SWIFT-4 on github with complete example code. You can use it. https://github.com/raoarafat/DeffieHelmanKeyExchange-Swift. Just download & use it.

SWIFT-4 Compatible.

Enjoy...