# iOS : App Store Approval Process - Declaration of Use of Encryption

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval, ios5

I would like to know more about the encryption declaration in App Store Approval Process.

I have an app that connects to server via HTTP ( not HTTPS ) . Sensitive information is encrypted by public key in App , then send to server by HTTP POST .

In server ( which is written in PHP ) , will decrypt the information using private key , then provide corresponding actions .

For such operation, do I need to declare using encryption in App Store Approval process ? If yes , what information do I need to provide to Apple ?

Comment: Check [Using SSL in an iPhone App - Export Compliance - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance)

Comment: How to differentiate which case requires declaration or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application has some feature that uses the encryption / decryption of the data which transferred through the Web APIs you don't needed to mention that while submitting application.

The reason is encryption / decryption is getting used while data transfers from server to Application.

**Important Note :**

- If your application internally using encryption / decryption for some data operations than it should be declared properly while submitting the application
- By doing not so can leads to application rejection & also if such activities found after approval process than Apple can permenantly remove your application from the store

Hope this helps to everyone.

Comment: @Raptor its my pleasure