# soundcloud iOS encryption

Tags: ios, encryption, soundcloud

I have developed an iPad app that integrates with SoundCloud using the libraries mentioned at https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI

My app needs to be able to post sounds to SoundCloud using these libraries. The libraries are all included as submodules in my git repo using

```
git submodule add git://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client.git
git submodule add git://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI.git
git submodule add git://github.com/nxtbgthng/JSONKit.git
git submodule add git://github.com/nxtbgthng/OHAttributedLabel.git
git submodule add git://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudUI.git
```

Now my question is, when I submit the app to the app store what encryption settings should I use? Does SoundCloud only do authentication and then send the data in the clear, unencrypted? Or is the data encrypted before sending to SoundCloud?

This is important because Apple threatens "severe penalties" for apps that use encryption without authorisation.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the above mentioned libraries you can be sure all communication is done via HTTPS (encrypted). See [SCConstants.m](https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI/blob/master/Sources/SoundCloudAPI/SCConstants.m#L35) and you'll find that all API endpoints carry the `https` protocol.

On submitting your app Apple will ask if you're app is implementing any cryptographic algorithms. The libraries aren't doing so. They only use algorithms that are already present in iOS. So if you're not implementing any on your own, you're safe.

Comment: That would be nice, but this says otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance