# What is the reason of Apple asking if I have included encryption in my new submitting app?

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store-connect

While iOS developers submit their new apps in itunes connect, Apple every time asks if developer included some encryptions in apps.

Why Apple pays so important attention for that?

**Addition:**
If I include **Security.framework** to my app, should I check checkbox on on question: if I added encrypted content to my app?

Comment: As for Security.framework - probably yes, but I couldn't verify this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably has to do with US export restrictions.

I found [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance) which points to [this blog](http://tigelane.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html) which details how to obtain permission.

Comment: Thank you, very clear answers

Answer (score 1):

It's to comply with US laws for exporting encryption products. You cannot ship products with strong encryption to some countries, such as Iran, Libya and others. Although... this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: If I include Security.framework to my app, should I check checkbox on on question: if I added encrypted content to my app?