# Apple's guidelines, regarding Network communication, encrypted data

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, web-applications

I am going to need to have encrypted messages between my app and my server.
I was going through apple's documentation to find something about that issue. 
(basically I need to encrypt the way the communication is going on so that no other app can imitate that and use my server)
Does anyone know if this can pose a problem with Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No apple has no problem with this, but....

If you are using strong encryption you will have to get a licence, look at this [site](http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/encfaqs6_17_02.html) for more details. The documents they provide when get the licence you will have to upload to apple  when you publish your app.

I also found [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance) which points to [this blog](http://tigelane.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html) which details how to obtain permission.