# Which ECCN should I use for iOS app which uses HTTPS?

Tags: ios, app-store

My apps uses only HTTPS encryption (as I understand all of this correctly, manually I didn't use any encryption in my code)

So which ECCN code should I choose for "Annual Self Classification Report"?

> (4) Export Control Classification Number (ECCN), selected from one of
>   the following:
>
> - (i) 5A002
> - (ii) 5B002
> - (iii) 5D002
> - (iv) 5A992
> - (v) 5D992

Also what about `AUTHORIZATION TYPE` - `ENC` or `MMKT`?

> (5) Encryption authorization type identifier, selected from one of the
>   following, which denote eligibility under License Exception ENC
>   §740.17(b)(1):
>
> - (i) ENC
> - (ii) MMKT

Comment: I'm researching this as well. I believe the 'A' in those codes indicates hardware and the 'B' indicates test equipment. I am leaning towards 5D992 based on this post:
https://www.altova.com/blog/ern-registration-for-ssl-use-in-mobile-apps/

And also the sample spreadsheet from BIS uses 5D992 for their sample app:
https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/licensing/red-flag-indicators/223-new-encryption/1238-how-to-file-an-annual-self-classification-report

Comment: see related post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance

Answer (score 7):

Some research into the ECCN codes turns up the following link https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/licensing/commerce-control-list-classification/export-control-classification-number-eccn

From that I gather that **5Dxxx** should the categories (**5**: Telecommunications and Information security, **D**: Software).

As for the numbers, this https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/component/docman/?task=doc_download&gid=2337 seems to be a good place to look for further information.

Reading that I think **5D992** should be a good ECCN, but I can not say for sure in your specific case. Skim the document and notes through and see what applies best.

As of ENC or MMKT.

`License Exception ENC authorizes certain exports, reexports, and transfers (in-country) of items described in paragraph (a) of this section for the internal “development” or “production” of new products by 'private sector end users,' wherever located, that are headquartered in a country listed in supplement no.`

While `MMKT` is Mass MarKeT as far as I've concluded. https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2010/06/25/2010-15072/encryption-export-controls-revision-of-license-exception-enc-and-mass-market-eligibility-submission

All in all, **MMKT** should probably be good if you're not yanking with the SSL modules or do anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 5):

5D992 & MMKT should be fine as you are only using existing https modules.

(But that's just my best guess, no formal advise of any kind!)