# Objective-C library recommendation for AES-256 in CTR mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encryption, aes

I'm looking for recommendations on an Objective-C library for AES-256 encryption in CTR mode. I have a database full of data encrypted with [another library using CTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529772/interoperability-between-two-aes-algorithms) and seems the included CCCrypt only supports ECB or CBC with PKCS#7.

Any idea on the best portable library I should use? I'm not looking to port the original implementation as I don't have the required knowledge in cryptography and hence, that's-a-bad-idea (tm).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to implement this using OpenSSL. It is not Objective C, but rather "plain" C code, but since the built-in encryption algorithms in the iPhone also rely on plain C, this should hopefully not make that big a difference.

There is a tutorial on [The Rare AiR](http://www.therareair.com/2009/01/01/tutorial-how-to-compile-openssl-for-the-iphone/) on how you can compile the OpenSSL library for iPhone.

Hope this helps,
Claus