# How to decompress an AES-256 encrypted Zip file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compression, aes, winzip

I am looking for a compression library to use in iPhone application supports decompressing     ***AES 256-bit*** archives built in `Winzip` compression utility.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compression API on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone)

Comment: See also [Objective-C library recommendation for AES-256 in CTR mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530746/objective-c-library-recommendation-for-aes-256-in-ctr-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you very much for the help I finally ened up using ZipArchive library from:

http://www.artpol-software.com

I had couple of obstacles such as compiling the library to armv6/armv7/i386 architectures but finally it worked out for me, I am more than happy to share the compiling process if any body want to use ZipArchive, amazing library.

Comment: can you share the compiling process?

Comment: @Krishnan: Do you mind if i post this as a Question and Answer it my self so everyone who is interested in this get benefit too'?

Comment: @Krishnan: i have been told that you need to ask this question your self and i will be more than happy to answer it.

Comment: Actually, posting a question and answering it yourself is just fine.  You might consider leaving it open for a day or two before accepting your own answer in case others have different and/or better ways of doing it.

Comment: @Chris Lively: ok I will do it very soon.

Answer (score 5):

zlib is part of the iPhone sdk and is a well established and free option. If you're using Xcode you can add it to your project by:

1. Right clicking on the Frameworks folder in your project (you can do it elsewhere but that's likely where you want to put it)
2. Select add file
3. Select existing frameworks
4. Select libz.1.2.3.dylib

Comment: careful this does not support AES 256 compressed files.