# Video uploading in iphone using http post method

Tags: iphone, ios, http, video, post

I want to upload a video using http post method. But due to size of video i think the request is time out. Can anybody tell me how to compress a video that is store in documents directory?

Answer (score 0):

zlib is part of the iPhone sdk and is a well established and free option. If you're using Xcode you can add it to your project by:

1. In the project navigator, select
   your project
2. Select your target
3. Select the 'Build Phases' tab
4. Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries'
   expander
5. Click the '+' button
6. **Select libz.1.2.3.dylib**
7. (optional) Drag and drop the added
   framework to the 'Frameworks' group

Reference 1: [How to Decompress an AES-256 Encrypted Zip File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063725/how-to-decompress-an-aes-256-encrypted-zip-file/4063949#4063949)

Reference 2: [How to “add existing frameworks” in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4/3377682#3377682)