# merging app resources - mac

Tags: c++, macos, merge

I have a mac app and want to hide it's resources. On windows, I simply made a resource file, but those don't seem to be existent on Mac. So I decided to follow the advice of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069065/hiding-or-encrypting-app-resources) link.

What I'm going to do, in another application which will prepare the resources beforehand, is take ALL my resources (text files, images, sound files, etc) and convert them each to `CFData` objects. Then I'm going to store them in a `CFDictionary` object with the filename as the key. After that, I'm going to save the dictionary to a file.

Problem is, CFDictionary objects don't know how to archive themselves, and I can't use Foundation objects, just Core Foundation. Is there a way to convert a `CFDictionary` to a `char*` and save that? Or will I have to save the keys and values individually and read them later to recreate a `CFDictionary`? If so, how would I convert the `CFData` objects?

Comment: I made a software just for that with optional AES256 encryption, developer tools to decrypt in Xcode are inside the app Enjoy!
http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/55122/loot-locker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this interesting page](http://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_utilities/libsecurity_utilities-32566/lib/cfutilities.h?txt) which has a utility method for converting a `CFDictionary` to `CFData`:

```
inline CFDataRef makeCFData(CFDictionaryRef dictionary)
{
    return CFPropertyListCreateXMLData(NULL, dictionary);
}
```

I don't know if it would work with images and sounds, though. You may have to convert those to `CFData`s first.

Comment: yeah, I can convert them to a `CFData`. Thanks this was what I needed!