# How to convert encrypted data to string

Tags: iphone, encoding, cryptography, aes

I have encrypted NSData using the code posted in [Any cocoa source code for AES encryption decryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039940/any-cocoa-source-code-for-aes-encryption-decryption) (Answered by Rob Keniger). Now I need to check the encryption is correct or not. For that I converted encrypted NSData to NSString, using the code

```
NSString *string=[[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[cipherData bytes] length:[cipherData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but when NSLog ed, it shows (null). My doubt is does the crypt() function encrypt data in different encoding rather than NSUTF8StringEncoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall,NSData can't directly transfer to NSString,I have a suggestion,you can make this NSData to Base64 NSString,and if you wan't to covert back,then use Base64 from NSString to NSData,find A "GTMBase64.h",that will help you

Encode

```
NSString *imageStr = [GTMBase64 stringByEncodingData:imageData];
```

Decode

```
NSData *imageData = [GTMBase64 decodeString:imageStr];
```